# Serializing object that contains NotSerializableException objects

Tags: java, csv, serialization

I'm trying to save an account object. It holds multiple different portfolios, each portfolio has a number of different investments. Each investment has an object that uses org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser. When I go to serialize the account so I can load it later, I get the java.io.NotSerializableException.

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: `I have no idea how to fix this.` Hard to tell without you showing us some code, but make the Objects that you do not want to serialize as `transient`

Comment: Thanks! This allowed me to serialize the account object. The only problem is that when I go to load the account obj again, all of the CSV data is null.

Comment: Again: Hard to tell without you showing us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the csv parser field in your `Investment` class as `transient`. Also *make sure you initialize* the transient csv parser field after deserialization by implementing `readObject` in your `Investment` class, so that it won't give you a `NullPointerException` in case the field would get dereferenced after deserialization. You'll need to add a method with the following signature to your `Investment` class:

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

and properly initialize the csv parser in it.

See [this article about serialization in java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html) or the [java serialization specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#a2971) for further details.

Comment: Okay, so, the CSVParser is within a Data object in my Investment class. The Data object is initialized in the Investment constructor. I'm not sure how to implement readObject() in my case. I need to initialize Data within a method readObject and then put readObject in my constructor?

Comment: @jonbon So it's the `Data` object that's actually holding a reference to the non-serializable `CSVParser`. If the `Data` object should otherwise be serialized together with the rest of the object graph (except of course the non-serializable `CSVParser`) then you should add the `readObject` method to the `Data` class instead. In essence, `readObject` gives you a chance to customize deserialization of an object. Whenever you need to work around a non-serializable field, you will have a chance to do so in the `readObject` at deserialization.

Comment: Similarily, implementing `writeObject` gives you a chance to customize serialization.